# Is ODL-SDNiApp still supported?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I am trying to test ODL-SDNiApp and found it not updated since Helium on this page https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/ODL-SDNiApp:User_Guide. So, is it still supported by Opendaylight? if not,  please list me some useful tools or methods for inter SDN controller communication.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the project page https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/ODL-SDNi_App:Main, it last participated in the Boron release but it doesn't look like it's been active since. You can try the project mailing list or contact the listed committers. If it is inactive as it appears, perhaps you might want to try to reboot it.

Comment: Actually I contacted them and no one replied! Thanks